# XAMPP to Hosting Server

Tags: database, xampp

Is there a way to transfer my local host XAMPP database to Online hosting Server? There is a lot of data and i cant retype it, so please suggest a way to transfer the whole database.

Comment: what database are we talking about? MySQL? Don't you have an option to export it as `.sql` script and run it against your new database server?

Comment: Yes it is in MySQL, where to find that option in xampp??

Comment: I only want database to be transferred and not the php files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and log in with your credentials, click on the database you want to export. On the right side you'll see an Export tab, click it, select SQL as format, and then GO. This will generate a script that will let you re-create your database somewhere else.

On your hosting environment you'll have to manually create a database, and run the generated script using SQL tab, this will re-create your schema, and populate your database with your previous records.